# NFTs sent to a Polygon version of our ETH MultiSig Wallet ! What do?

Tags: gnosis-safe

I'm quite new to this so I'm struggling.

**Situation:**
Friend sends Polygon NFTs to our 1.3.0 ETH Gnosis Safe Wallet.
Link to one of them here:
[One of the transactions](https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x8b77d6969cc24596245c65167afac96b9f0bac72b87295d067963c7ba4c9898a)

I tried watching this video but got confused quickly, especially around the part where it says "*Network where you want to deploy to*".
[Video link](https://www.loom.com/share/ca34aabcd62747fb9fb89bd463b4c741)

**Endstate:**
I want the NFTs in our ETH wallet or in a Polygon version of our wallet.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would have said that your assets are lost but luckily a solution exists.
You have to deploy your gnosis safe from the same address you used on Eth mainnet (`0x373bf86F1bC19D2534ccC0c8A0660B8D927aCD5c`), with the same nonce and the same arguments.
To make sure you don't make a mistake during this process, I would recommend scripting and testing the process locally before broadcasting transactions.
You would basically need to :

1. put some matic on your safe deployer address
2. broadcast empty txs to polygon to make the nonce of the account go up
3. broadcast the exact same tx you did on mainnet to deploy your safe, on polygon (to the same address, from the same address, with the same arguments (including the same salt), with the same nonce)

If you do this correctly, you will have effectively replicated your mainnet safe on polygon at the same address, and you will be able to get your asssets back.

Edit : to be exact you only need to deploy a contract from the same deployer and the same nonce to take control of the address you send the NFTs to. Doing this will deploy a contract to the address holding your NFTs. You need to make sure the contract you deploy there will be able to send you the NFTs back.

Comment: Thank you, though I feel more confused now !

Comment: It seems you finally did it ;) https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x34c3663524f9f72a9a8698e644cacbe1b45d6856854a7a140dd8fc30dfef97b0#internal

Comment: I managed to set up a wallet on the Polygon network with the same address as the ETH wallet. But the NFTs are still not there. ?? I'm not sure what I must do next